# Recovering state of batch process after server failure

Tags: database, architecture, microservices, backend, data-processing

I believe that topic speaks for itself.
I would love to read your opinions and maybe possible solutions on this?

Lets say that we have first, simplest scenario:
There is 1k of new products that needs to be imported to system via server.
Products is only one table in database, no relations needed.

Imagine that we are trying to upload this data and in the middle it fails but there is no rollback, data is saved partially.
Let's say 200 from 1000 products were saved into db.
Since you got message that data was saved partially because of server failure you want to import the same data once again but it is not very effective to check if every of product exist in database. How do we restore such state of a batch process to start it from 201 product not starting from beginning?

Thanks!

Comment: Are the to be ingested records ordered? Are they unique?

Comment: They arent ordered, lets say that it just plain json but every product is unique

Comment: Okay. Do the to be ingested records have unique identifiers or are they generated by the database?

Comment: Lets say that Product name will be unique which makes sense to not duplicate them

Comment: Okay. How do you do the ingestion? For example are calling a stored procedure as many times as many records you have? Or are you using a technique like [Table-Valued-Parameter](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1483/using-table-valued-parameters-tvp-in-sql-server/) to pass multiple records at the same time? Or xyz?

Comment: I am using microservice for that. I am writing code in JS but it is more like language independent. I want to recover state of failed batch job in the backend service

Comment: Does that mean you are issuing API calls for each to be inserted record?